# Regex for grepping exact phrase in git log

Tags: python, git, github, grep, git-log

Currently, I am working on mining software repository in `github`. I use the `git log command` to get the commit logs. But when I only need to find the commit logs contain a specific word, some unexpected logs also have shown.

For example, I need the commit log contains word `HBASE-792`. I used command `git log --grep='HBASE-792' --oneline`. But these logs have shown:

```
HBASE-7921. TestHFileBlock.testGzipCompression should ignore the block checksum
HBASE-7923 force unassign can confirm region online on any RS to get rid of double assignments
HBASE-7928 Scanning .META. with startRow and/or stopRow is not giving proper results; REVERT.  NEEDS SOME MORE WORK
Fix overlogging; part of HBASE-792 patch
Patches to alleviate HBASE-790 and HBASE-792
```

What I need are only the last 2 commit logs which exactly contain `HBASE-792`. What pattern should I write in grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try piping the output of git log to grep, and using the `-w` flag of grep. Here go the sample run for a test repo I made:

```
Test $ git log --grep='HBASE-792' --oneline
09172fd asd sHBASE-792 asd
bea6628 asd HBASE-792s asd
3100179 asd HBASE-792 asd
4cb3200 HBASE-792
```

with `-w` flag:

```
Test $ git log --oneline | grep -w "HBASE-792"
3100179 asd HBASE-792 asd
4cb3200 HBASE-792
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try running the grep in Perl mode:

```
git log --grep='\bHBASE-792\b' --perl-regexp --oneline
```

All I did was to put word boundaries around `HBASE-792`.  With them in place, your pattern should no longer match to e.g. `HBASE-7923` which appears at the start of one of the lines which should not match.

Comment: But it can't be applied in python